# How to call external websites from a asp.net mvc application which has AAD setup

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I have followed the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp and successfully created the web application and deployed to Azure. My application needs to get IP and geolocation of the logged-in user. I am using https://ip-api.io/json/ and http://checkip.dyndns.org/ to get these information. I am doing webclient calls to fetch the data:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string jsonstring = client.DownloadString(url);
        return jsonstring;
```

This is working when I run the code using IE but fails when using Chrome, Firefox and IE in Private browsing. 
I get the Microsoft screen to enter my email address and password but then get the error message "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again."
If I comment the code which is calling these external links, I am able to login.

I am not sure what is causing this behaviour and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How is this external API call related to authentication?

Comment: that's what I'm not able to understand. I noticed if I put a breakpoint in Index method in HomeController, the breakpoint does not hit when I enable the code to call the external apis. Do we need to set permissions to call these apis in Azure App registrations?

Comment: Uhh no I don't think so

Comment: I have changed the implementation and used the following code to get the ip. But this also does not work, that is I am not able to sign in using my AAD account:  private string GetIp()
        {string ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
            {ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            }
            return ip;
        } Is there any kind of restriction on AAD which is preventing the application to get the user's IP address?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by making use of optional claims:
"idToken": [ 
             { 
                "name": "ipaddr", 
                 "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
              }
        ]

This should be added in the app's manifest on Azure.

More details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims